# node.js and async module error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an undefined variable in my code and not sure what the error in my code is:

I get client as undefined when I call getClient...
I have a soap client creation singleton and I have:

```
    var mySingleton = (function() {
    var soap = require('soap');
    var async = require('async');
    var instance;
    var client;

    function init() {
        var url = "http://172.31.19.39/MgmtServer.wsdl";
        var endPoint = "https://172.31.19.39:9088";     
        var options = {};
        options.endpoint = endPoint;        

        async.series([

                      function(callback) {
                          soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, result){
                              console.log('Client is ready');
                              client = result;
                              client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('admin-priv', 'password'));
                              callback();
                          });
                      }
                      ], 

                      function(err) {
            if (err) 
                return next(err);
        });


        return {
            getClient : function() {
                console.log("I will give you the client");
                **return client;**
            },

            publicProperty : "I am also public",

        };
    };

    return {
        getInstance : function() {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = init();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

    module.exports = mySingleton;
```

so my consumer is :

```
var soapC = mySingleton.getInstance();
var mySoapClient = soapC.getClient();
```

I get mySingleton.client is undefined.

Why?

Comment: a) `client` is not a property of `mySingleton` b) the `client` variable is assigned *asynchronously*.

Comment: Why are you using `async.series` with a single function?

Comment: I will be adding more...I put one in there for brevity

Comment: How is it that client is not a property of mySingleton? How do I change that TO be a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there are better solutions than this one, but it shows you that it can be implemented easier (without async, without singleton):

```
var soap = require('soap');
var client;

var url = "http://172.31.19.39/MgmtServer.wsdl";
var options = {
    endpoint: "https://172.31.19.39:9088"
};

module.exports = {
    getClient: function (callback) {
        if (client) {
            callback(null, client);
            return;
        }
        soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Client is ready');
            client = result;
            client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('admin-priv', 'password'));
            callback(null, client);
        });
    },

    publicProperty: "I am also public"
};
```

And when using the client:

```
// using the client
var mySoapServer = require('./path/to/above/code.js');

mySoapServer.getClient(function (err, client) {
    if (err) { /* to error handling and return */ }
    client.someRequestMethod(myEnvelope, function (err, response) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

There might be a problem when your Soap-Clients gets into trouble (there is no logic to reconnect in case of error). For this you could have a look at the source code of Redis-Client, MySQL-Client, MongoDB-Client, ...

**Edit**

Some comments on the different aproaches:

The Singleton-pattern is not needed here. Node will execute this JS file only once and further `require`s get only a reference to the exports. There is no need to create an IIFE scope - the variables won't be visible outside, only the exports.

Programming in Node.js is (besides some special cases) an all-async way. If not done consequently, it just doesn't work or fails/succeeds only if you have good/bad luck.

Error handling looks very much like a lot of boilerplate, but it's necessary in most cases.

Comment: what were the shortcomings of my approach? In my implementation, you just called getClient, synchronously without providing a callback and then did whatever needed doing. everything else is abstracted. I might have to make more asynchronously call, in the init step, in the near future, the async allows me to do that...

Comment: @reza: The synchronous call is just what did not work. You need an asynchronous callback for async tasks. Promises would be a nice abstraction however.

Comment: OK, I understand. Using async is just to be prepared when more steps have to be made for initialization. It's fine. Probably the `next` is some kind of refactor/copy+paste error, because it's not defined.

Comment: but I think the problem is still that client needs to be a static member variable for MySingleton. How do I do that?

Comment: It is static. As it is evaluated only once, the export object and the closure variables exist only one => static. Everybody calling `require('yourcode.js' ` gets this object. The first caller will have to wait for instantiation, following callers reuse the created instance.